# How to import a module that is in a different folder in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, ecma

Cordial greetings, I hope you are well.

I would like some guidance on how I can import a module that is in another folder.

**Here is an image:**
[image]

However when importing the module it generates me error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../controllers/index.js'
Require stack:
```

I would be very grateful for your guidance.

Comment: ../../controllers/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand, how path works. You are missing one more directory skip in your path.

```
const module = require('../../controllers/index.js'); //as you are in route module, you need to go back to controller directory(so ../../path of file)
```

For more details on path, you can check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/).